# Add2Any print preview instead of print

Tags: plugins, joomla

I use AddToAny plugin to a Joomla website. I need to replace the code so I can "preview page" instead of "print" (ctrl+p).
I found AddToAny files into /plugins/content/addtoany, but I see no code for [print service code](https://www.addtoany.com/services/print_button)

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in the plugin for links generation, unless if you're talking about the css class to add a specific link (see below).

---

All the links are generated via the AddToAny's js: http://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js

As you probably already know, all the rendering is generated with classes (powered by the js file above): https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/standalone_services

```
<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
    <a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_pinterest"></a>
    <a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
```

This means the links themselves are not "generated" in the plugin, so your solutions are whether try to override the plugin via the [MVC override plugin](https://github.com/ghazal/plg_mvcoverride) or develop your own solution.